# Asynchronous database logging in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have WCF service which requires Information Request,Response and exception logging. Due to synchronous logging, wait on logging to complete might have performance impact. I am looking for ways to implement database logging asynchronously.

Below are some of the points

1.WCF is service is load balanced

2.If I write the log in server cache and have another program to read from cache and log to DB, in case IIS is recycled then server cache is cleared, end up with missing the information

3.Don’t want to use any external library like Log4Net etc.

Can anyone help me with idea on Asynchronous logging in WCF?

Comment: You can configure enterprise library to log into the database, but you don't want that... Just wondered if there is any particular reason you don't want to use any 3-rd party lib?

Comment: Did not want to use any third party Dll's.